# Calculate: $16^{4321}\pmod{9}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

How to calculate: $16^{4321}\pmod{9}$

I think I have to use the Euclidean Algorithm for this or Fermat's Little Theorem but im really at a loss here. Anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: Well, have you tried using the Euclidean algorithm for Fermat's little theorem? What part of the problem are you stuck on?

Comment: It might help to notice that $16 \equiv -2 \mod 9$ togeather with $(-2)^3 \equiv 1 \mod 9$.

Comment: It straight out and out Fermat little theorem.  What happened when you applied it?  It should simply be two steps to solve.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use Euler's extension of Fermat's theorem: $x^{\phi(9)} \equiv 1 \bmod 9$.

Now, $\phi(9)=6$ and $4321 \equiv 1 \bmod 6$ and so $16^{4321} \equiv 16 \equiv 7 \bmod{9}$.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $16 \equiv 7 \mod 9$. Therefore $16^3 \equiv 7^3 \equiv 1 \mod 9$

Then note that $4321 = 3\cdot 1440+1$. Hence

$$16^{4321} \equiv 16^{3\cdot 1440+1} \equiv (16^3)^{1440}\cdot16 \equiv 1^{1440}\cdot 16 \equiv 1\cdot 16 \equiv 7 \mod 9$$

Answer (score 1):

This can be done without Euler Phi
$$16^{4321}=2^{17284}=2\times (2^3)^{5761}=2\times8^{5761} \equiv 2\times(-1)^{5761}\equiv-2\equiv 7\pmod 9$$

Answer (score 1):

We work in the ring $\mathbb Z/9\mathbb Z$.

We have $16=7$ and the powers of $7$ modulo $9$ repeat each three consecutive numbers; in fact $7^1=7;\space 7^2=4;\space 7^3=1$.

It follows $$16^{4321}=7^{4321}=7^{3\cdot1440+1}=(1)^{1440}(7)^1=7$$

Comment: You should show me who you are, sir Downvote. Or at least, explain the reason for your -1. If you disapprove the right thing, you do not deserve to be a member of StackExchange.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try:
$$\begin{align*} 
16 &\equiv 7 &\pmod{9} \\
16^2 &\equiv 49 &\pmod{9} \\
16^2 &\equiv 4 &\pmod{9} \\
16^4 &\equiv 16 &\pmod{9} \\
16^6 &\equiv 64 &\pmod{9} \\
16^6 &\equiv 1 &\pmod{9} \end{align*}$$

> Then you will have $(16^{6})^{720}16^{1} \equiv 16 \equiv 7 \pmod{9}$